# Bash- Fetching a value stored in terraform file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terraform

I am required to fetch a value stored in a terraform file in bash script.

```
cat custom.tfvars
Val1 = {a1 = "12", b2 = "0.5", "count" = 2}
Val2 = {a1 = "14", b2 = "0.5", "count" = 1}
```

I want to write a script to fetch value of `Val1(count)`.

Thanks.

Comment: Will it always be that format or could it have more line breaks in?

Comment: It will be the same format always. It's a read-only file

Comment: consider reviewing [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question; in particular ... provide the code you've attempted so far, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -En '/^Val1/{s/(^.*)(count.*= )([[:digit:]]+)(.*$)/\3/p}' custom.tfvars
```

Enable regular expression interpretation with -E and then process lines that start with "val1" Split the line into 4 sections based on regular expressions in parenthesis and substitute the line for the 3rd section only, printing the result

Answer (score 5):

While you can use normal Unix text processing tools to access this value (such as with the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66904060/2291321)) you may also find it useful to use a tool that can properly parse HCL. Thankfully Terraform ships with the command line command [`terraform console`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/console.html) which will enable you to interact with Terraform configuration and state data in an initialised workspace.

Given a file called `custom.tfvars` that has this content:

```
Val1 = { a1 = "12", b2 = "0.5", "count" = 2 }
Val2 = { a1 = "14", b2 = "0.5", "count" = 1 }

val1_fmt = {
  a1    = "12"
  b2    = "0.5"
  count = 2
}
```

You'd also need to declare the variables so you might have something like this:

```
variable "Val1" {}
variable "Val2" {}

variable "val1_fmt" {}
```

You can then initialise the directory with `terraform init` and then run `terraform console` to interact with the configuration either interactively (the default) or by piping the console commands into `terraform console` like this:

```sh
echo "var.Val1.count" | terraform console -var-file custom.tfvars
2
```

Note that if you had defined your variables in `terraform.tfvars` or a file ending with `.auto.tfvars` it would be [used automatically without the need to pass the `-var-file` flag](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files).

Using `terraform console` here would allow you to also read equivalent structures that are formatted differently:

```sh
echo "var.val1_fmt.count" | terraform console -var-file custom.tfvars
2
```

Comment: You put a lot of effort into answering a question that had almost no effort.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is using [HCLQ](https://github.com/mattolenik/hclq) (command line tool for querying and manipulating HashiCorp HCL) here are some examples

```
cat custom.tfvars | hclq get 'Val1.count'
```

or you can update the value

```
cat custom.tfvars | hclq set 'Val1.count' 5
```